# How to implement state transition involving multiple states

Tags: state-machine, state-machine-workflow

So far when dealing with simple state machines I hadn't have a situation where upon transitioning from one state to another the context needs to pass through other states. That's to say, for example there is an entity which has following states: **Running, Shutdown**, and **Disabled**, and the transition from **Running** to **Disabled** functionally goes through the **Shutdown** state:

```
Running->Shutdown->Disabled
```

The question is how in terms of proper state machine implementation I should do this kind of transition with more than two states involved.

Best regards

Comment: I think shutdown is not a proper state here, since the transition conditions from shutdown to Disabled are not defined or? And the system can not be in that state infinitely long time, e.g. I have got feeling that it is some transient intermediate state, which is held by the system some amount of time.

Comment: The Shutdown state actually exists - it's when the module is is issued a shutdown signal and the module may reside in this state for some time. The Disabled state means the module receives a signal to release the associated resources which obviously requires shutting a module down.